# azure function app - how to disable many functions in a durable

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I have an azure function app where many functions (serviceBusTrigger) send messages to one orchestrator then routed to an activity that does the hard work.

[image: azure durable function]

I was struggling to understand, when I have to disable all the functions (for any reason), if there is a particular order I need to follow.

Comment: wondering can you use [Disable] tag for your serviceBusTrigger ?

Comment: @Turbot not clear, do you refer to the `disable` entry in the `function.json`?

Comment: you can use tagging disable on your functions.
        [FunctionName("ServiceRunFunction")]
        [Disable]
        public static async Task ServiceRunTrigger(......)

Comment: @Turbot sorry, I missed to specify the language I was developing with, that is Python. I suppose I can't do this with Python

Comment: i see, how about binding script config file `function.json`, there 
{
    "disabled":true,
    "bindings":[
        // ... bindings here
        {
            "type": "bindingType",
            "direction": "in",
            "name": "myParamName",
            // ... more depending on binding
        }
    ]
}

Answer (score 0):

As your diagram shows, your durable function actually forms a function chain. Therefore, when you need to disable all functions, you need to turn it off from servicebustrigger to activity, otherwise an error will occur.

For example, you can disable functions using below steps:

`servicebustrigger1 -> servicebustrigger2 -> servicebustrigger3 -> orchestrator -> activity`

Answer (score 0):

I would always disable upstream to downstream. However, this should not be required with orchestrations.

In your case if you disable "activity" first you will still receive data from your service bus and your orchestrator will fail. Depending on your retry policy (assuming you are using "CallActivityWithRetryAsync") these will either eventually fail and get saved in a storage account, or they will retry until you reenable you reenable your activity function.  This will create backpressure and could cause additional scaling as your application attempts to process and retry incoming data.

If you disable your service bus trigger first this will allow current hard working processes to complete and cutoff the flow of data to the system allowing your azure function to properly scale down. This is how I would do it, but that's not to say that you have to do it this way. Orchestrations, if built properly, are smart enough to retry exceptions once an activity function is reenabled. So this is preferred IMO but not necessary.